# Using image taller than the navbar

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have this navbar in a project:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img th:src="@{/img/bootstrap-solid.svg}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Kleber App Store
  </a>
</nav>
```

Instead of this:

```
    <img th:src="@{/img/bootstrap-solid.svg}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Kleber App Store
```

I want something like that:

```
    <img th:src="@{/img/bootstrap-solid.svg}" width="120" height="240" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Kleber App Store">
```

but without change the height of the navbar (the image should overlap the navbar on the beginning, and leave out for the area below, like a cascade).

I've tried add `style="position: absolute;"` following some answers here on the stackoverflow, but with this solution, the image is displayed with a little gap from the top, and behind a `list-group` in the area below the navbar.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: hi Kleber, could you add a demo to your question pls

Comment: something like that https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/wq84623n ?

Comment: and did you try position: absolute solution with top:0 on img and margin-bottom: 120px; on navbar?

Comment: just did. same result: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/wq84623n/12/

Comment: ok the gap is still there. But it is there due to paddings on navbar and navbar-brand. So if you would reset them (padding-top: 0;) you should be fine https://jsfiddle.net/m7k6ozhu/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the image but, with the `navbar` bootstrap class. The `navbar` class has `height: auto;`. That's why it increases its size with the content inside it.

You can try customizing the navbar height by

```
.navbar {
  height: 3rem;
}
```

OR

```
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

with

```
<span class="pl-3">Brand Name</span> <! –– padding-left or whatever required ––>
```

Comment: He looks for a solution  "without change the height of the navbar"

Comment: Yeah, but the answer could work if: 1) the image could have margin-top 0; right now there is a gap between image and top. 2) there is a `list-group` in the area below the navbar, and the image right now is behind this element. Regardless, if there is a solution which do not involve change the height of the navbar, would be great.

Comment: @Vova I got that but, all I am asking is to just recreate the bootstrap navbar height CSS, instead of keeping it auto.
Or else we can do ```position: absolute;```  the ```img``` tag and then wrap the brand name with a ```<span>Kleber App Store</span>``` and then give it a ```padding-left: 3.5rem;```
Just thinking of other ways.

Comment: I've tried the sugestions from the answer, but I think do not work? maybe I did something wrong. jsfiddle-.https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/2uLrwvds/4/